# China passport holder transit more than 11 hours in Seoul (KE) to YVR

Tags: visas, transit-visas, south-korea, chinese-citizens

I'm going to Vancouver (YVR) and will transit in Seoul for 11 hours. I'm holding  a passport from China.

Do I need any visa to transit in Korea?

Answer (score 3):

> Do I need any visa to transit in Korea?

Normal Chinese passport holder can avail TWOV (transit without of visa) visa to stay in Seoul  with a visa issued by Australia, Canada, New Zealand,Switzerland, USA or an EEA Member State . Since you have a visa from Canada, therefore you can simply enjoy TWOV in Seoul airport.

Source: [Visa And Passport](https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/timatic.htm)

National China (People's Rep.) (CN)
Embarkation China (People's Rep.) (CN)
Transit Korea (Rep.) (KR)       /Destination Canada (CA)
ALSO CHECK DESTINATION INFORMATION BELOW

Visa required, except for Passengers with a Hong Kong (SAR
China) passport, or:
Visa required, except for Passengers with a Macao (SAR China)
passport, or:
Visa required, except for Nationals of China (People's Rep.)

with a visa issued by Australia, Canada, New Zealand,
Switzerland, USA or an EEA Member State For details, click here if:
For details, click here 
Visa required, except for Nationals of China (People's Rep.)

with a group visa issued by Japan if in transit through Korea
(Rep.) when: For details, click here 
TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets transiting

Seoul Incheon (ICN), for a max. transit For details, click here time of
24 hours. 
Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets transiting Seoul Incheon (ICN), participating in the Transit Tourism

Program for a max. transit For details, click here time of 72 hours.
Leaving the transit area is permitted, provided staying in
Seoul, Incheon or Gyeonggi Province. Leaving the tour group is
not permitted.

**Transit Tour  Incheon Airport**

Also as a Chinese citizen , you are also entitled for a free transit tour programme since you have a 11 hour layover , you might be eligible to register and go outside airport for a minimal fee.

for complete registration process, you can simply follow the link below:

[Transit Tour Programme](https://www.airport.kr/pa/en/d/2/3/5/index.jsp)